# Unable to pass AWS CLI commands in double quotes in json syntax

Tags: bash, aws

I'm working with the below script,getting syntax error as unable to fetch credentials from secrets manager. "username":"AWS CLI command of access Key i have entered", "password":"AWS CLI command of secret key i have entered". Great if anyone can help

```
#!/bin/bash

# Send the POST request and capture the response
response=$(curl -k \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-X POST \
-d \
'{
"username":"'aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region ap-south-1 --secret-id poc | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r '.Access_Key''",
"password":"'aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region ap-south-1 --secret-id poc | jq --raw-output '.SecretString' | jq -r '.Secret_Key''"
}' \
https://<region>/api/v1/authenticate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with quoting in your payload data, and those command pipelines do not automatically get executed.

Instead, consider preparing the JSON payload document first, and then call `curl` with the prepared data:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Prepare JSON payload containing username and password.
payload=$(
        aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --region ap-south-1 --secret-id poc |
        jq '.SecretString | fromjson | {username: .Access_Key, password: .Secret_Key}'
)

# Submit the payload to the API and capture the response.
response=$(
        curl --silent \
                -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
                -d "$payload" \
                "https://{{region}}/api/v1/authenticate"
)
```

This only requires a single `aws`+`jq` invocation to get the AWS credentials since `jq` can pull multiple pieces of data into a JSON object in one go.  The `SecretString` key's value is an embedded JSON object, so we use `fromjson` to decode it in the `jq` expression before accessing the embedded fields.

Comment: `Curl` don't know about this switches: `--variable` and `--expand-url` AFAIK. At least, not in `man curl`.

Comment: @GillesQuénot Ah, added in release 8.3.0 it seems. I'll delete those extra fancy bits. https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/11346

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, using shell's *here doc*:

```
#!/bin/bash

username=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value ... | jq '...')
password=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value ... | jq '...')
anotherVariable=foobar

# Send the POST request and capture the response
response=$(
    curl -k \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
        https://<region>/api/v1/authenticate
        -d @/dev/stdin <<EOF
        {
            "username": $username,
            "password": $password,
            "anotherKey": "$anotherVariable"

        }
EOF
)
```

The `-X POST` is not needed when using `-d`.

---

If you master `jq`, maybe opt for @Kusalananda answer, or mix them. If not, this is maybe more easily re-usable if you are not fluent with `jq`.